# Apache Server - Wrong X.509 Certificate only on some virtual hosts

Tags: https, apache2, virtualhost

I have two virtual hosts using the same certificate... yet apache returns the localhost certificate for only one of them.

`openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:443 -servername domainA.com -tls1_1` shows that Apache's httpd is returning the `localhost.crt` X.509 certificate.  *However*, `openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:443 -servername fake.com -tls1_1` shows the correct `domainA.crt` X.509 certificate.

As far as I can tell the configuration settings should be effectively the same for each domain.

## `ssl.conf`

```
Listen 443 https
[... other preincluded defaults (probably) ...]
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
[...]
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.key
[... other preincluded defaults (probably) ...]
</VirtualHost>
```

## `httpd.conf`

```
[...]
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
Listen 80
ServerName domainA.com:80
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
[... other preincluded defaults (probably) ...]
<VirtualHost *:443>
  VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/html
  ServerName domainA.com:443
  ServerAlias domainA.com

  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/domainA.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf/domainA.key
  SSLCACertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/domainA.crt
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/html
  ServerName fake.com:443
  ServerAlias fake.com

  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/domainA.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf/domainA.key
  SSLCACertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/domainA.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

## `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1 domainA.com fake.com localhost
[...]
```

order doesn't matter in `/etc/hosts`.

How do I get Apache to use `domainA.{crt,key}` for `domainA.com`?

```
$ httpd -version
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Server built:   Aug  8 2019 11:41:18
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was the *global* `ServerName` setting... why that should have any effect, *especially* considering that it shouldn't be used in the first place since **http doesn't have any concept of or use for a "server name"** when using virtual-host settings with SNI and the HTTP `host` header...

Just replace `ServerName domainA.com:80` with `ServerName why-are-you-even-asking-for-this-apache.damn-apache.you-must-break-stuff-on-purpose.your-literally-going-out-of-the-way-to-make-things-break.why-do-you-hate-us.info:80`.

Problem solved.